# Vue-good-table Invalid Date when date is null using

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using a table component for Vuejs called vue-good-table. 
It allows you to format your columns with different formats like string, number and date.

My issue today is related to the date formatting. I'm being able to format the column properly, however, some of the values that come from the database are null, and then it appears a label `Invalid Date` for those rows that have null dates.

Is there a way to configure those columns as nullable or format them in a way that I prevent this message to be shown? I'd rather leave the table cell empty instead of displaying that label.

The following example shows the scenario that I'm describing

```
<template>
  <vue-good-table
    :columns="columns"
    :globalSearch="true"
    :paginate="true"
    :rows="rows">
  </vue-good-table>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'Table',
    computed: {
      columns() {
        return [{
          field:"fieldA",
          label:"fieldA",
          type:"number"
        },{
          field:"fieldB",
          label:"fieldB",
          type:"date",
          inputFormat: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
          outputFormat: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
        }];
      }
    },
    rows() {
      return [{
        fieldA: 1,
        fieldB: null
      },{
        fieldA: 1,
        fieldB: '2017/01/04'
      }];
    }
  }
</script>
```

In that case, I would have one field with the date formatted correctly, and another field with a label `Invalid Date`

Thanks

-- UPDATED --
This problem was fixed in most recent versions.

Comment: Don't you have a small snippet that reproduce the error?

Comment: @acdcjunior Updated! See if that helps for a better understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I have just realized the formatFn function overrides the input and output format options, since it will only use the function to format the data. Not sure if it's the best aproach, but instead you should probably format the data yourself on the function (or format the data before passing to the table). Here's an example using moment:

```
{
    label: 'Date/Time',
    field: 'date',
    type: 'date',
    formatFn: function (value) {
        return value != null ? moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') : null
    }
}
```

---

I had the same issue and I was able to format the data using the formatFn function (https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table#formatfn-function).

```
{
    label: 'Date/Time',
    field: 'date',
    type: 'date',
    dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
    dateOutputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss',
    formatFn: function (value) {
        return value != null ? value : null
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This problem was fixed in the most recent versions, but your solution works indeed. Thanks :)